# Limit the dynamic markers to one

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, markers, ng-map

In the below plunker, i can add so many markers by selecting marker tool. But i need to limit it to only one. after adding one marker it should disable or the user should not be able to put another marker on map. 
i have used ngMap https://ngmap.github.io/ . can anyone please help me

```
 <ng-map zoom="13" center="37.774546, -122.433523"
map-type-id="ROADMAP"
street-view-control-options="{position: 'LEFT_CENTER'}">
<drawing-manager
  on-overlaycomplete="vm.onMapOverlayCompleted()"
  drawing-control-options="{position: 'TOP_CENTER',drawingModes:['polygon','marker']}"
  drawingControl="true"
  drawingMode="null"

  rectangleOptions="{fillColor:'red'}"
  circleOptions="{fillColor: '#FFFF00',fillOpacity: 1,strokeWeight: 5,clickable: false,zIndex: 1,editable: true}" >
</drawing-manager>
```

the plunker is here : http://plnkr.co/edit/Hboz7DnD30JZAiNgD1G5?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *modified* example demonstrates how to remove `marker mode` from drawing control once the marker is added on map (*in order to prevent the user from adding another markers*)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngMap']);
app.controller('DrawingManagerCtrl', function () {
    var vm = this;

    vm.drawingControlOptions = {
        position: 'TOP_CENTER',
        drawingModes: ['polygon', 'marker']
    }

    vm.onMapOverlayCompleted = function (e) {

        if (e.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
            vm.drawingControlOptions.drawingModes.splice(1, 1);  //remove marker mode
        }
    };
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script> 
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="DrawingManagerCtrl as vm">
        <ng-map zoom="13" center="37.774546, -122.433523"
                map-type-id="ROADMAP"
                street-view-control-options="{position: 'LEFT_CENTER'}">
            <drawing-manager on-overlaycomplete="vm.onMapOverlayCompleted()"
                             drawing-control-options="{{vm.drawingControlOptions}}"
                             drawingControl="true"
                             drawingMode="null"
                             rectangleOptions="{fillColor:'red'}"
                             circleOptions="{fillColor: '#FFFF00',fillOpacity: 1,strokeWeight: 5,clickable: false,zIndex: 1,editable: true}">
            </drawing-manager>
        </ng-map>
 </div>
```

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/fsmNQjZHBaKimdWOw3ZK?p=preview)

### Option 2

Another approach would be to disable marker from displaying on map once the first marker is rendered:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngMap']);
app.controller('DrawingManagerCtrl', function () {
    var vm = this;
    vm.markersCounter = 0;
    vm.onMapOverlayCompleted = function (e) {
        if (e.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER) {
            vm.markersCounter++;
            if (vm.markersCounter > 1)
                e.overlay.setMap(null);  //disable marker from diplaying .. 
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=placeses,visualization,drawing,geometry,places"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="DrawingManagerCtrl as vm" ng-click="disableClick(1)">
        <ng-map zoom="13" center="37.774546, -122.433523"
                map-type-id="ROADMAP"
                street-view-control-options="{position: 'LEFT_CENTER'}">
            <drawing-manager on-overlaycomplete="vm.onMapOverlayCompleted()"
                             on-click="vm.onClicked()"
                             drawing-control-options="{position: 'TOP_CENTER',drawingModes:['polygon','marker']}"
                             drawingControl="true"
                             drawingMode="null"
                             rectangleOptions="{fillColor:'red'}"
                             circleOptions="{fillColor: '#FFFF00',fillOpacity: 1,strokeWeight: 5,clickable: false,zIndex: 1,editable: true}">
            </drawing-manager>
        </ng-map>
    </div>
```

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/TdokuE1eSjG0zyLqwaoK?p=preview)

Comment: if i do like this, is it  wrong. please see the plunker here https://plnkr.co/edit/WNpUjufCYCoW6MhCoEzE?p=preview

Comment: You asked:  _or the user should not be able to put another marker on map_ i demonstrated how to remove marker option. Do you need to **disable** marker button?

Comment: yeah, i got your point. Thanks for your help. my another question is , i am disabling the click using normal angular js code. can i do like that also or is  that the wrong way of doing it

Comment: No, my answer was wrong. i nee the thing like which you did above. Thank you once again

Comment: Just updated the answer (see option 2), in that case there is no need to hide a button, may be it more preferable solution

Comment: Thanks, In the second option you have used  `on-click="vm.onClicked()"` which is neither not defined nor not necessary.

Comment: And also, Could you please tell me, how to get the co-ordinates of the point which the user put the marker.
In the second solution , if the user tries to put another marker, the marker is not displaying or not adding at all?