# Limit the dynamic rectangle to one

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

In the below [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CR1T1udqPQqj2G37BlBi?p=preview), I can add so many polygons by selecting polygon tool. But I need to limit it to only one. After adding one polygon it should disable or the user should not be able to put another polygon on map. 
I have used ngMap https://ngmap.github.io/ .

Almost same replica of [limit the dynamic markers to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606890/limit-the-dynamic-markers-to-one) .But I am not able to do for rectangle.

```
   <ng-map zoom="13" center="37.774546, -122.433523"
            map-type-id="ROADMAP"
            street-view-control-options="{position: 'LEFT_CENTER'}">
        <drawing-manager on-overlaycomplete="onMapOverlayCompleted()"
                         drawing-control-options="{{drawingControlOptions}}"
                         drawingControl="true"
                         drawingMode="null"
                         rectangleOptions="{fillColor:'red'}"
                         circleOptions="{fillColor: '#FFFF00',fillOpacity: 1,strokeWeight: 5,clickable: false,zIndex: 1,editable: true}">
        </drawing-manager>
    </ng-map>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Kg4AGHQt3dyRDca2P2Ky?p=preview)

```
if (e.type == "rectangle") {
   $scope.drawingControlOptions.drawingModes.splice(0, 1);//remove marker mode
}
```

`e.type` is string here. and you need to remove "**rectangle**" from **0** th position of your array.

Comment: Thank you. it worked. such a small thing  took some time to me